# Jenkins : How to get sonar environment variables

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

How to get sonar environment variables like sonar host, sonar project key or sonar workspace in order to use them in email with Jenkins plugin: Editable Email Notification.

any help or idea ?

Comment: the question is, how do you store them? if you use a sonar-project.properties file to determine them, you gain multiple benefits. First they are readable and injectable, b they are living and changing with the code. But that is just an imho :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `withSonarQubeEnv()` plugin function to pull the values. You have to configure Jenkins with the Sonar variables you want it to use. You can find more info about that at the link below. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find documentation from Sonarqube what variables are being provided. You might want to run something like `sh "env"` within the `withSonarQubeEnv` stanza to get an idea.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline

Answer (score 0):

As @chizou explains, you can use `withSonarQubeEnv()` to get environment values to use in your pipeline. I only want to add more information, however I want to add extra information on how to use it.

In [Jenkins sonar plugins source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sonarqube-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/sonar/SonarBuildWrapper.java) you can see that that the available variables injected will be:

- SONAR_CONFIG_NAME
- SONAR_HOST_URL
- SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN
- SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL
- SONAR_EXTRA_PROPS

This variables are configured from jenkins manager, and `SONAR_EXTRA_PROPS` is a custom parameter where you can add `key=vaule` pairs separated by coma.

To use in scripted pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                withSonarQubeEnv('Sonarqube') {
                    script{
                        // check the SONAR_ variables in all environment vars
                        def output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env')
                        echo "Output: ${output}"    
                        
                        // or use directly
                        echo "${env.SONAR_HOST_URL}"
                        echo "${env.SONAR_CONFIG_NAME}"
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```